Tr8x8 Lead screw - What standard, and where do I find dimensions such as pitch (mean) diameter
I'm trying to pick a lead screw and stepper motor to form a linear actuator for a personal project. I'm trying to do the calculations on the lead screw to get from input torque to max lifting force. To do this I need various dimensions of the thread of the lead screw.
I've found a number of metric lead screws that use the following naming:
Tr8x1
Tr8x2
Tr8x4
Tr8x8
The first seems to have a pitch of 1mm, and the latter 3 have a pitch of 2mm with starts of 1, 2, 3.
What standard does this follow?
DIN103 and ISO2904 only define an 8mm diameter thread with a pitch of 1.5mm
